# upload framework extension .swf php

Tags: php, zend-framework, upload, flash

i want to upload a .swf format and i am getting an exception "false extension" and i tried to put a validator on the extension and it still didn't work any ideas how to upload .swf and do i need a special uploader. This is my form code.

class Admin_Form_Banner extends ZendX_Form_Designed {

```
public function init() {
    $this->setEnctype(self::ENCTYPE_MULTIPART);
    $this->setMethod(self::METHOD_POST);
    $this->setMethod('post');

    // Add an email element
    $this->addElement('text', 'banner_title', array(
        'label' => 'Banner Title',
        'required' => true,
        "class" => 'required',
        'filters' => array('StringTrim')
    ));

 $this->addElement('select','banner_type',array(
     'label'=>'type',
    'required'=>TRUE,
     'class'=>'required',
     'multiOptions'=>array('1'=>'Image','2'=>'Flash','3'=>'HTML')
 ));
    $this->addElement('text', 'banner_link', array(
        'label' => 'Banner Link',
        'required' => true,
        "class" => 'required url',
        'value'=>'http://www.',
        'filters' => array('StringTrim'),
    ));
    $this->addElement('select','link_open',array(
        'label'=>'choose how do you want the link to open ?',
        'required'=>TRUE,
        'multiOptions'=>array('self'=>'Same Page','_new'=>'Tab Page')
    ));


    $this->addElement('checkbox', 'is_active', array(
        'label' => 'Is Active',
        'required' => true,
        "class" => 'required',
        'filters' => array('StringTrim')
    ));

    $banner_position = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('banner_position');
    $banner_position->setMultiOptions($this->getBannerPositions())->setLabel('Banner Position');

    $this->addElement($banner_position, 'banner_position');


    $this->addElement('hidden', 'file_path', array(
        'required' => true,
        "class" => 'required',
        'Extension'=>'.swf'
    ));


    $this->addElement('submit', 'submit', array(
        'ignore' => true,
        'label' => ''
    ));
}
```

Comment: never seen "ZendX_Form_Designed" ? what class is this. I cant find an File Element in your source code, could you please provide more information?

Comment: ZendX_Form_Designed is extend for zend_form so its like dealing with zend form

Answer (score 1):

Well it's a Zend_Form_Element_Hidden how could you receive a fileupload from that element ?
Maybe you've made some customization to allow that but we can't really guess with this limited code sample.

Comment: yea you are right there is so much customization anyways i change it to a normal file upload thanks anyways